# PHP and fancy boolean

Tags: php, boolean, boolean-expression

Having some problems with booleans in php, would be very grateful if anyone could explain why the following doesnt work

```
$var = "asdas";

    // or this if(!isset($var) || ($var && !$var)){
    if(!isset($var) || (is_bool($var) != true && is_bool($var) != false)){
        echo "is not a boolean";
    }else{
        echo "it IS a boolean";
    }
```

the output is always -> "it IS a boolean"

Thanks in advance

---

Thanks for your help, yea I realise what I've done (school boy error).

**Solution**

```
$var = "asda";
if(!isset($var) || (is_bool($var) === false)){
    echo "it not a boolean";
}else{
    echo "is IS a boolean"; 
}
```

Comment: Why the down votes? Any explanation?

Comment: Hmm... why negate the logic in your solution? It just makes it harder to read when you come back to it later on. Perhaps take a look at the solution I provide in my answer below for a "better" way of achieving the same thing.

Comment: the reason why i negated the logic was because I only wanna do something in my actually code when its false... if true -> just continue. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
(is_bool($var) != true && is_bool($var) != false)
```

`is_bool()` returns either `true` or `false` so you are eliminating the first `echo`.

Change your code to this:

```
$var = "asdas";

if(isset($var) and is_bool($var)){
    echo "it IS a boolean";
}else{
    echo "is not a boolean";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`is_bool($var)` is always either true or false.

In other words, `(is_bool($var) != true && is_bool($var) != false)` will always evaluate to <s>true</s> false.

Comment: Simple but complete answer :-) is_bool checks the type of the variable. So the variable is of type boolean or not -> binary result ^^

Comment: Actually it always evaluates to `false`, not to `true`.

Answer (score 3):

```
(is_bool($var) != true && is_bool($var) != false)
```

What this does:

Statement should return `true` **ONLY** if `$var` is *NOT* a boolean **AND** $var *IS* a boolean.

As you can imagine, `$var` can not NOT be a boolean and be a boolean at the same time. <sub>(Seems like `$var` is having some kind of personality disorder :))</sub>

Answer (score 2):

```
(!isset($var) || (is_bool($var) != true && is_bool($var) != false))

(!isset($var) || (!is_bool($var) && is_bool($var)))

(!isset($var) || false)
```

`$var` is set so the result is always `false`.